# Check which NET Hosting Bundle is in use

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have version 2.1.5 and 2.2.7 installed of .NET Hosting Bundle (but I'm not sure if everything is using 2.2.7). Therefore, I need to see if 2.1.5 is being used by anything on my server before making the decision to uninstall it.

[image: Installed Programs displaying .NET Hosting Bundles]

Does anyone know of a way to check if 2.1.5 is currently in use by anything?

[image: My task manager current display]

Comment: Can you rename the folder and see if windows lets you? (`C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\2.1.5` that is)

Comment: Programs might show you multiple versions, but the actual installed ASP.NET Core module (core component of the Hosting Bundle) has only a single copy usually at C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2. In your case, that copy should be 2.2.7. However, ASP.NET Core 2.2 is end-of-life, so you shouldn't have any 2.2 stuffs on your machine.